# How do I create an observable of an array from an array of observables?

Tags: arrays, swift, rx-swift

I have an array of `Thing` objects that I want to convert to `ConvertedThing` objects, using an asynchronous function that returns `Observable<ConvertedThing>`.

I'd like to create an `Observable<[ConvertedThing]>` that emits one value when all the conversions have completed.

How can this be accomplished?  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [`.merge()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) to combine the array of observables into a single observable, and then use [`.toArray()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/to.html) to get them as a list in a single event.

For RxSwift 3+ use:

```
let arrayOfObservables: [Observable<E>] = ...
let singleObservable: Observable<E> = Observable.from(arrayOfObservables).merge()
let wholeSequence: Observable<[E]> = singleObservable.toArray()
```

For previous versions:

```
let arrayOfObservables: [Observable<E>] = ...
let singleObservable: Observable<E> = arrayOfObservables.toObservable().merge()
let wholeSequence: Observable<[E]> = singleObservable.toArray()
```

Comment: My starting point is an array of observables, rather than a single one.  So I want to get from `[Observable<ConvertedThing>]` to `Observable<[ConvertedThing]>`.

Comment: @Paul: Sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 30):

For future readers:

Using [`.merge()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) and [`.toArray()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/to.html) will emit a single element when all observable sequences complete. If any of the observables keeps emitting, it will not emit or complete.

Using [`.combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) will return an `Observable` that emits the full list every time any observable changes:

```
let arrayOfObservables: [Observable<E>] = ...
let wholeSequence: Observable<[E]> = Observable.combineLatest(arrayOfObservables) { $0 }
```

Comment: The detail of an `Observable` completing or not makes such a big difference, thanks for pointing out. kennytm's solution will only work if your `Observables` are completing; otherwise use `combineLatest()`.